# sails mongo retrieve selected column

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, sails.js, sails-mongo

I am using sails-mongo adapter for my sails project.

I want to retrieve selected column from collection.

Here is my collection document data

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("54449e2ecaf08cf40fc8704f"),
   "name": "demo",
   "display_name": "demo",
   "status": true,
   "createdAt": ISODate("2014-10-20T05:31:26.714Z"),
   "updatedAt": ISODate("2014-10-21T13:02:41.595Z") 
}
```

I want to retrive "name" and "display_name"

same as in mysql like "SELECT name, display_name FROM TABLE";

-Thanks :)

Comment: Which sails version are you using ?

Answer (score 3):

Waterline allows you to query like this in order to achive that

```
User
.find({
    'where': { 'or': [{'firstname': name}, {'lastname': name}] },
    'select': ['uuid','firstname','lastname','createdAt']
})
```

dmarcelino a Sails collaborator commented on Apr 29 about this issue and waterline does support it without having to pull in native.
[.select() #73](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/73)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `native` function in `sailsjs`, like so:

```
ModelName.native(function (err, Collection){
  Collection.find({}, { 'name': 1, 'displayName': 1, '_id': 0 }, function (err, result){
     if(err){
       /* handle error */
     }
     else{
       /* Do somethig with the result */
     }
  });
});
```

The `native` function allows us to run a native mongodb query in Sailsjs.

You can check the query in a `MongoDB` console using:

> db.collectionName.find({}, { 'name': 1, 'displayName': 1, '_id': 0 })

Comment: Is there not any way directly from sails-mongo (Waterline) to find ??

Comment: AFAIK, the current version (0.10.12) of `Waterline` does not support `Projection`.